# website shows spam page which doesn't appear in ftp

Tags: html, web, ftp, virus

there seems to be spam e-mails being sent out about my site, not from my e-mail address, but with a link about my site.

The page it links to is not one I placed there, but I though "simple enough, go into ftp, delete the page and change all passwords"
...
nope.

Went into ftp, and the file simply doesn't seem to exist.

The link is below, but warning - this is a spam page on the site without my permission, thus make sure your pc is thoroughly protected before following the link.

Any tips?

tlc-sussex(dot)com/christianslump/

EDIT - oh joy - it's redirecting any 404.

Comment: Well, what do the log files of the http server say where the content is served from?

Comment: It says the files are being served by mysite/vg2/... but there is no such folder there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the password for the hosting account yet?  Do that now.  How is the site coded?  I suspect your controller files have been heavily modified.

update:  I'm asking on how the site is coded.  I'm guessing either a framework or some sort of content management system (CMS, like Joomla or Drupal)  Are you the programmer of the site, or perhaps the key user maintaining the site?   oops.. I see its a Wordpress CMS site, and I'm guessing you are the key admin updating the site.  Somewhere one of your php controller files has been hacked, and needs to be replaced.  Did you install the site, or did someone else do it.  You can easily replace the wordpress core files, but you may have custom addons to contend with.

Comment: I'll change the password now. It seems that it is a 404 system - any page that doesn't have a "page" is redirected there.

Answer (score 1):

ok, found the problem-

In the Wordpress plugins there was a maliceous plugin changing the 404 - and hiding itself from the Wordpress plugins menu. I've deleted the files and 404 has gone back to normal; and all wordpress passwords now changed. Updating to the latest wordpress now!

Comment: I would also recommend installing and running the wordpress plugin "Antivirus" it will do daily scans of all your wordpress files and email you if anything malicious is detected.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about HTACESS then try putting this URL HTACESS and redirect this URL to home page of your website.

Comment: Aye, I've thought of that. I'll update my htaccess file if I can't work out how it's there - but it would worry me that whatever it is still remains.

Comment: try doing 301 if that do not work then we can try different alternative.

Comment: As I couldn't find a solution, I was going to do this, but just discovered there's multiple pages, so can't be sure I've got them all with .htaccess. They all root from a folder called /vg2/ but I can't see that folder in my ftp.

Comment: is your website developed on PHP?

Comment: Yes, well, it's a Wordpress site.

Comment: then it should be treated as category/page/tag. you will not find any physical page for it. you can check it from wordpress admin